# Determining the domain of holomorphic function, the taylor series of function with its convergence's radius.

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

I need some help and correct my knowledge, please.

> Let $f(z)=(e^{z}-1)/(1+z+z^{2})$. Determine the largest domain $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $f$ is
>   holomorphic in $\Omega$.

Since $1+z+z^{2}=0\Longleftrightarrow z=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{3}i}{2}$, then $f$ is holomorphic in $\Omega=\mathbb{C}\setminus \left \{ \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{3}i}{2} \right \}$.

> Determine the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f(z)$
>   with center $a=1/2$.

How do I determine $\rho=\inf\lbrace|a-z|:z\in \Omega\rbrace$? Otherwise it would take time to determine a Taylor series in order to find its radius of convergence.

> Show that Taylor series of $f(z)$ with center $a = 0$ is given by
>   $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}z^{k}$, where $a_{0}=0$,
>   $a_{1}=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $a_{k}=(1-k)/k! + a_{k-3}$ for $k\geq 3$. Use them to determine $f^{(6)}(0)$.

I will use $a_{k}=f^{(k)}(0)/k!$. 
First we see that
$$
f'(z)=\frac{e^{z}(1+z+z^{2})-(e^{z}-1)(1+2z)}{(1+z+z^{2})^{2}}=\frac{f(z)(z^{2}-z)+1}{1+z+z^{2}}
$$
and
\begin{align*}
f''(z)&=\frac{(f'(z)(z^{2}-z)+f(z)(2z-1))(1+z+z^{2})-(f(z)(z^{2}-z)+1)(1+2z)}{(1+z+z^{2})^{2}}\\
&=f(z)\frac{(2z-1)}{1+z+z^{2}}-f'(z)\frac{(z^{2} - 3z - 1)}{1+z+z^{2}}\end{align*}
so determining a general expression of $f^{(k)}(z)$ will be awfully difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$, and $D(a,r)\subset \Omega$ (where $D(a,r)$ is the disc centered at $a$ with radius $r$), then the radius of convergence of the power series expansion of $f$ around $a$ it at least $r$. If $f$ can not be extended holomorphically in any larger disc, then the radius of convergence of the power series expansion of $f$ around $a$ it EXACTLY $r$.

In our case, 
$$
D\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\subset \Omega=\mathbb C\smallsetminus\big\{\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}\big\}.
$$
But 
$$
\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}\in \overline{D}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}\right),
$$
as
$$
\left|\frac{1}{2}-\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right|=\left|1+\frac{\mp i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right|
=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}.
$$
and hence $f$ can not be extended holomorphically in any larger disc.

Thus the radius of convergence of the power series expansion of $f$ around $\dfrac{1}{2}$ 
is exactly $\dfrac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$.